# What is the difference between Google Calendar and Google Tasks?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-tasks-api

I am confused what is the difference between Google Task and Google Calendar?

Initially I thought I wanted to use Google Calendar but now I realize that I want to use Google Task.

They even have different APIs. This just confuses me:

Google Task API: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Tasks_API

Google Calendar API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_dotnet

What is the difference between them?